# Automatically move to the next cell in a column only if criteria is met if not check the criteria in the next row and keep doing the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Sheet 1 - I have 3 columns (First Name, Last Name & Status)

Sheet 2 - I want the first cell in A column to only populate the First Name, if the status says "RESPONDED" in the status column and then automatically execute the same formula in the next row.

If the criteria is not met, then the formula needs to check the rest of the status column and check for the next status "RESPONDED" and then populate those details in ROW 2 and so on.

I hope I have explained what I need, if not let me know.

[image]

[image: !enter image description here]

Thanking you
Regards
AG

Comment: Hi, can you please give a brief example, eg. the first three (?) lines of Sheet 1 and and what you need in Sheet 2 then. That would make your requirement even clearer to me.

Comment: Hello Bogis, 

Appreciate the response. Please find attached a sample excel file to show you what I need. Comments are in Yellow in the sheets. There are two sheets, Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Please let me know if you can help. How do I send you the file ?

Comment: Hello Bogis,

I have attached the sheet 1 and 2 in my original message. let me know if you are able to take a look at it. There are two links to the samples sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have, If you have a subscription to Office 365 then you can use FILTER.

Comment: That was a really simple solution ! awesome ! Thanks Bogis, have a good one and stay safe.

Comment: It would still be awesome if we can get a formula to do the same. without filters. If you you do come up with some thing or any does, please let me know. Cheers

Comment: There is no formula that can do this without blank lines and without filters. VBA could, easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns are A, B and C of `sheet1`, and output starts from row 2 in `sheet2`.

To return first name:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$23,SMALL(IF("Responded"=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$23,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$23),""),ROW()-1)-1,1),"")
```

To return last name:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$23,SMALL(IF("Responded"=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$23,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$23),""),ROW()-1)-1,1),"")
```

To return response:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$23,SMALL(IF("Responded"=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$23,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$23),""),ROW()-1)-1,1),"")
```

- *Drag down formula.*
- *You may change cell references as your need.*
- *Row `2` to `23` covers sample data I was looking at.*

Comment: Tried it, everything is blank ! all the three columns are blank. Did you try it ?

Comment: Any Suggestion. Tried different things with the formulas you sent. Still no luck. It is giving false as result in the IF part.

Comment: HI Ashwin, if you post the exact formatting of your page (i.e. the columns referenced, where referenced from and how your text is formatted, particularly search term) I will adapt the formula to suit. The most likely causes are the ROW()-1 term which adjusts the small function to return the 1st then 2nd smallest etc - if you are starting search from other than row 2 you adjust this to suit OR the -1 immediately following ROW()-1)-1 adjusts the index function to show the correct member of the reference array, need to alter according to start row of reference array.

Comment: Hi Justin,

Here is the link to the file. Let me know what I have done wrong or what needs to be done. Thanks.
www.factore.in/excel/Book1.xlsx

Comment: Hello Ashwin, when I downloaded the file the equations had a number of @ symbols inserted ```=IFERROR(@INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$23,SMALL(IF("Responded"=@Sheet1!$C$2:$C$23,@ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$23),""),ROW()-1)-1,1),"") ``` I deleted the symbols and the formulas worked as expected.

Comment: Hi Justin,

Thankyou for the same, but in my formulas locally there is no @ symbols. I tried it again and it is still the same, all blanks. Is there are way you can send me the file?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, what version of Excel are you using? I have made a link to my public onedrive, let me know if it works I have not tried sharing this way previously. [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=EE0D1596342114D5%21109&cid=EE0D1596342114D5). This is the file you uploaded, I downloaded it and removed the @ symbols.

Comment: I'm using excel version 16.35, I downloaded your file, it is still blank. Is there some setting I need to turn on or change? checked the formulas, they don't have any @symbols. the cell are all blank as before. I don't get it, how come it is working for you and not here for me. let me know if there are any settings I need to change. Thanks Justin, appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry Ashwin, I cannot understand why it would not be working for you. They do not require the ctrl + shift + enter, and they work fine this end with no settings I am aware of. Try the suggestion from Karthick below, I will be interested to know if they work.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the help, will keep trying and if I get it to work, will let you know. I tried Karthick's too, but that is giving me an alert as I mentioned in the comment. that not working for now either. Will keep you posted. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Hi Justin, Just to let you know, I tried your answer in Google Sheets and it worked perfectly. I don't understand why it is not working locally on my system. If I figure it out, will let you know. Thanks again, stay safe, have a good one. Cheers

Comment: Hi Justin, Just to let you know, I got your formula working on my local excel copy, It was a simple workout, I just pasted your formula and hit "Cntrl + Shft + Ent" and voila, it started working. Dragging the formula down to the other cells doesn't work for this formula for some reason. Here it is, just incase you find yourself in the same situation, you can try this. Cheers, Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Much similar to Justin's response,

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1_img]

2 tables,

1. SourceTbl containing the actual source data
2. StatusTbl containing “unique” Status values

You can create a table by selecting the dataset and pressing `Ctrl + T`. Check the 'My table has headers' checkbox if you have one else Excel will auto-create one for you which you can then rename.

Table name can be modified in the 'Table Tools' ribbon -> Design Tab (at least any 1 cell in the table must be selected).

**Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2_img]

First, create a similar table structure as of SourceTbl but leave the cells in the table empty.

Cell F4 holds a data-validation dropdown list showing Sheet1’s StatusTbl entries. This cell is custom-named ‘myStatus’

**Cell A5** holds the following array formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SourceTbl[First Name],SMALL(IF(SourceTbl[Status]=myStatus,ROW(SourceTbl[Status])-ROW(INDEX(SourceTbl[Status],1,1))+1),ROW($A1))),"")
```

Copy-paste and hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

**Cell B5:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SourceTbl[Last Name],SMALL(IF(SourceTbl[Status]=myStatus,ROW(SourceTbl[Status])-ROW(INDEX(SourceTbl[Status],1,1))+1),ROW($A1))),"")
```

Copy-paste and hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

**Cell C5:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SourceTbl[Status],SMALL(IF(SourceTbl[Status]=myStatus,ROW(SourceTbl[Status])-ROW(INDEX(SourceTbl[Status],1,1))+1),ROW($A1))),"")
```

Copy-paste and hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

**NOTE:**

1. Any missed out rows can be retrieved by expanding the table in Sheet2 (Tables by default have 'calculated column' feature enabled which will automatically copy down the formula for each column respectively)
2. If your table in Sheet2 has blank rows it means you retrieved all matching data, the formula is set to show empty string if there is no data to retrieve.
3. You can change the 'myStatus' value in Cell F4 from the dropdown list as required. The corresponding data from the SourceTbl (Sheet1) is captured.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Karthick, tried the above, but when I paste the formula, I get an alert asking that I need to add an apostrophe into the formula.

Comment: @Ashwin - Can you pls paste a link here to the error / alert msg screenshot ?

Comment: Hi Karthick, Here is the link of the screeshot of the alert. 

www.factore.in/excel/alert.png

Comment: Ashwin, I hope you were able to update the Table names as mentioned in my post. You can either edit the table name per formula or update the formula per your choice of table names. Apologies for multiple customizations.